# How to fix "expected call-signature to have a typedef" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a switch case function inside my render JSX element that I am using in another const value based on the return values.

I tried looking for a solution to my issue online but none of the answers I found are helping my issue, even after trying them on my code.

```
function carouselClass(transitionTypeValue: any) {
            switch(transitionTypeValue) {
                //Different cases and their return values
            }
   }

   const classes = xyz(carouselClass(transitionType)) //Sample of where I'm using my switch function
```

The code runs fine on Typescript side but I get a linting error which says "typedef  expected call-signature: 'carouselClass' to have a typedef"

I tried my best to give enough context, please let me know if more is required as this is my first time posting a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Linter giving 'Missing Type definition' warning. Check this out- 
https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/typedefRule.ts for details.

Solution: You need to specify the return type for function explicitly

```
function carouselClass(transitionTypeValue: any):any {
            switch(transitionTypeValue) {
                //Different cases and their return values
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add return type if you are calling function and returning something.

```
    function carouselClass(transitionTypeValue: any):any {
            switch(transitionTypeValue) {
                //Different cases and their return values
            }
   }

   const classes = xyz(carouselClass(transitionType))
```

You should avoid using type *any* where ever you can.

Comment: Would _void_ be better than _any_?

Comment: Unless you don't return anything, you can't use void.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid returning any or value with multiple types, 
but if you still want to return multiple types of value, try to find similarity and create Enum type or Wrapper Interface, or you can try to create generic function.

```
    interface IClassType extend IClassA, IClassB {}

    function carouselClass(transitionTypeValue: any): IClassType {
            switch(transitionTypeValue) {
                // Different cases and their return values
                // Avoid returning multiple types, 
                // but if you still want to return multiple types of value, 
                // try to find similarity and create Enum type or Wrapper Interface
            }
   }

   const classes: xyz<IClassType> = xyz(carouselClass(transitionType))
```